# Stack Overflow doesn't accept my answers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

While posting answers, why doesn't Stack Overflow accept my answers? The message says that answers from this account cannot be accepted.

What can I do so that I can post answers again?

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) the message you see?

Comment: Have you been deleting some of your answers? Were they downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of your answers were deleted because they weren't actually answers (one of them was deleted by me). They were questions. You shouldn't have posted an answer unless you were trying to answer the question. We don't tolerate people repeatedly misusing the answer field, hence the answer ban.

Comment: okkk so how we can get privilege back

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Usually by improving your existing answers, although in this case all but one of them have  been deleted. You could concievably ask for some to be undeleted so you can provide real answers to them. The exact details of the answer ban are secret so its hard to be sure but it has been suggested that having high quality questions (which recieve upvotes) can help overcome an answer ban but that can't be confirmed.